# Issue with Javascript, need to re-verse an action

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ErDu/6/

It gets values and changes the CSS on those values based on the values selected.

User selects: start 2 end 4

2-3-4 get: css( "background-color","red" );

While the rest remain green, i want to be able to make this work like this aswell:

User selects: start 4 end 2

4-1-2 get: css( "background-color","red" );

I am kind of lost here, as i dont know how to do this, any suggestion is welcome.

JSfiddle posted here to:

html:

```
<form id="priceCalcForm">

    <p>from color</p>
    <select name="from_color" id="from_color" 
        style="width:25%;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" 
        onchange="placeColor()"
    >     
        <option value="" name="" selected="selected">....</option>
        <option value="tp1" name="">01</option>  
        <option value="tp2" name="">02</option>  
        <option value="tp3" name="">03</option>  
        <option value="tp4" name="">04</option>
    </select>

    <p>to color</p>
    <select name="to_color" id="to_color" 
        style="width:25%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;" 
        onchange="placeColor()"
    >
        <option value="" name="" selected="selected">....</option>
        <option value="te1" name="">01</option>  
        <option value="te2" name="">02</option>  
        <option value="te3" name="">03</option>  
        <option value="te4" name="">04</option>
    </select>

    <table id="timer_table" cols="24" width="100%" 
        style="text-align:center; background-color:#80A74C"
    >
        <tr style="border-style:outset; border-color:green;">
            <td id="color1">01</td>
            <td id="color2">02</td>
            <td id="color3">03</td>
            <td id="color4">04</td>
        </tr>

        <div id="totalPrice"></div>
    </table>

</form>
```

JS:

```
var picked_time = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= 23; i++ ) { // loop the rest
    picked_time['tp'+i] = i;
}

var end_time = {}; 
for(var i = 1; i <= 23; i++ ) { // loop the rest
    end_time['te'+i] = i;
}

function placeColor() {

    var evF = 0; // end values 0
    var evT = 0; // end values 0

    var theForm = document.forms["priceCalcForm"]; // target form

    var from_color = theForm.elements["from_color"]; // target from level <select>
    var to_color = theForm.elements["to_color"]; // target from level <select>

    evF = picked_time[from_color.value]; // get the value etc from there
    evT = end_time[to_color.value]; // get the value etc from there

    $( 'td[id^="color"]' ).css( "background-color", "" );

    if (evF <= evT) {
        for( var index = evF - 1; index < evT; index++ ) {
            $( "#color" + ( index + 1 ) ).css( "background-color", "red" ); 
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (evF > 0 && evT > 0) {
    for( var index = evF; index != evT; index = (index+1) %5 ) {
        $( "#color"+( index ) ).css( "background-color","red" ); 
    };
    $( "#color"+( index ) ).css( "background-color","red" );
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ErDu/7/)

Where `5` is the number of cells you have + 1. It would be better not to hardcode it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code, to manually handle the index var.

```
for( var index = evF - 1; index < evT; index++ ) {
  $( "#color"+( index + 1 ) ).css( "background-color","red" ); 
};
```

Example:

```
var index;
var i = 0;
while(i < Math.abs(evT-evf)) {
  index = evf+i;
  if (index > MAX_INDEX) {
    index -= MAX_INDEX;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, i dont understand what you mean

Comment: You should copy the code I gave you, in the part where you do the for loop. Just replace the MAX_INDEX with the number of values you may have.